# php-mysql fetch next and previous id from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
**id**         **username**         **activity**
1              user1                  activity-like
2              user1                  activity-share
3              user3                  activity-like
4              user4                  activity-like
5              user1                  activity-share
6              user6                  activity-like
8              user1                  activity-share
9              user3                  activity-like
10             user5                  activity-share
```

(Note: there is no id = 7)

I am trying to use php-mysql to fetch the activity made by user1 and get the id. In this case the activities have the id (1, 2, 5, and 8).

```
$currentId = 5;
```

I want to get the next and previous ids if they exist (in this case 2 and 8).

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE `username` = 'user1' AND id > '$id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($fetch) == 1){
while (){

}
$result = $fetch['id'];
}
```

I am not sure how to write the query for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

For next id,

```
SELECT id from tablename where username = 'user1' AND id > $currentId ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1;
```

For previous id,

```
SELECT id from tablename where username = 'user1' AND id < $currentId ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a `union` query as below:

```
 (SELECT ID, USERNAME, ACTIVITY FROM MAIN WHERE username = 'user1' AND ID < '$id'
 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)
 UNION 
 (SELECT ID, USERNAME, ACTIVITY FROM MAIN WHERE username = 'user1' AND ID > '$id'
 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1);
```

First query fragment should return ID = `2` if it exists and second should return ID = `8`.

Comment: I believe MySQL will require each part of the `UNION` to be enclosed in `()` in order to have its own `ORDER BY` clause.  `(SELECT * ... ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT ...ORDER BY...)`

Comment: Would also note that it is not advisable to `SELECT *` in a `UNION` query. Be explicit about the column lists.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Updated the answer with both the suggestions as I don't see any downside with them. Thanks!